dynamic matrix capabilities
My target goal is to create matrix which will looks like that. Ideal goal is to recreate such matrix:


start with Current Date only matrix, and have available slicer to introduce MTD or YTD or both, so it will be multiple selection slicer which will expand matrix.

Have another slicer which will allow me to get the values in Thousands or Milions

Have another slicer which will allow me to switch currencies (I have columns Revenue_CommonCurrency and Revenue_TransactionCurrency)


Currently I've loaded only minimum required tables which is - fact_sales, dim_stores, dim_companycode and dim_calendar. There is many dim_stores to one dim_companycode and one dim_companycode to many fact_sales, as well as one dim_calendar (on dateint value) to many dateint values in fact_sales.
The measures I've done are fairly simple:

SumOfRevenue = SUM(fact_sales[RevenueTransactionCurrency])

PY = as above with time intelligence function on dateadd

and the delta as a difference between

I was thinking about some calculation groups? I don't know if it's matter of DAX or Visual design or both?
